# how to make ui device independent

Tags: android, device

I'm developing an android app.for that i'm using device of size 1024*600.
I want to make my app device independent.its should run on small device as well as lager device than current.how to make this?i made changes in manifest file.but doesn't work.

```
 <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:resizeable="true"
                  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read android document well. For supporting your app to multiple screens and device refere this [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page explains everything related to UI development. There are number of things to do, providing different XMLs, use of density independent pixels, etc. Read this page carefully, you will understand what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest combination of things

- Use **dp** instead of **px**
- Use Relative Layout as more as you can
- Create different layout for different density and resolution device like  [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html). This link is already mention in above two answer also
- Necessary to cover maximum phone my setting minimum and maximum sdk `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"  android:targetSdkVersion="4" />`

**And finally** to understand better see [how to create different layout for different screen size](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Yuva you can create different layouts for screen sizes such as

**layout-large, layout-small, layout-xlarge ,**

So u can manage the screen sizes by creating different layout folders. And then copy your layout XML files to different size layouts. Now it supports to all types of screen sizes .

Comment: but how can i use these layouts layout-large, layout-small, layout-xlarge while loading activity

Comment: No need to manage Activities just create the layouts as i mentioned above and check it in Palette window you can see the difference in sizes based on that u can manage the Screen sizes for your app and it supports all the screens .......